# How to store object as string?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've never used Firebase before, and am trying to connect a real-time database to my Unity app. Right now my app pulls data from a Json file and stores it as a string. To avoid breaking the rest of my program (I'm very new to programming and don't have the skills to rewrite it, but am learning), I want to convert the Firebase snapshot into a string and read it the way my current Json file is. Is that possible? The snapshot is an object file, and I need to get the string data from it.

This is the code to capture the snapshot.

```
DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
```

I also have this string declared.

```
private string gameDataFileName = "data.json";
```

Then this is the function to load the data from the file.

```
private void LoadGameData()
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, 
    gameDataFileName);

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        string dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        GameData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData>(dataAsJson);

        allRoundData = loadedData.allRoundData;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Cannot load game data!");
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to convert the snapshot into a Json or string so I can plug it into dataAsJson? Or if not can anyone tell me the proper way to do this? The app is a trivia game that downloads the questions and answers when starting the app. I don't need the data to refresh, I just want to be able to update the questions without forcing the user to download an update, hence my reason for using Firebase.

Is there a different way I should be doing this? I've searched every corner of the internet and everything I read is either beyond my comprehension or doesn't work in my situation.

Comment: just serialize it  I use newtonsoft, but I understand latest unity has it built right in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the raw JSON of a `DataSnapshot` call its [`GetRawJsonValue()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#getrawjsonvalue). You should then be able to pass that into your `JsonUtility.FromJson` method.